# Long, Double and 64 bits of memory

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

Long and double require 64bits of memory. This causes these types to require two address spaces.

On 64bit jvm's is this still the case ? As these values can now fit into a single address space does
this mean that these types are now stored in a single address space ?

Does this have implications for threading where the use of volatile is required on these types to ensure
that each individual address space is not updated out of order ?

Comment: Java should be virtual machine independent: so it means that a java program is always executed the same way, regardless of the way it is implemented in the virtual machine...

Comment: @CommuSoft That is not true, strictly speaking. You get the same guarantees. But anything not covered by those guarantees is free to change. So it is allowed (in fact, it is encouraged) for a 64 bit VM to treat `double` and `long` writes as atomic, but you get no guarantee that it will happen.

Comment: See previous answer like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173208/value-integrity-guarantee-for-concurrent-long-writes-in-64-bit-openjdk-7-8

Comment: @biziclop: sure, but it is therefore unwise to count on the vm to solve all kinds of problems. For instance a vm doesn't have to store in 64 bit either: one could use 80 bits and use some weird encoding, as long as the operations (`+`,`&`,...) behave the same.

Comment: "Address Space" means the entire range of possible addresses that can be referenced by any instruction.  You might mean "Addressable unit", which is the smallest thing that has its own unique memory address.  On most modern processors that is an 8-bit byte, so a long or a double occupies 8 addressable units.  You might also be referring to the largest operand that can be fetched in a single cycle of the processor's local bus:  That's where 32-bit vs. 64-bit matters.  A 64-bit computer can fetch a long from memory in a single bus cycle.  It takes two bus cycles on a 32-bit computer.

Comment: Think of the parameter slot numbering as *just a fancy (dumb) numbering scheme*. There's nothing that says the VM *has to* follow this for the order on the stack. It was probably designed that way so the JLS definition mapped directly to stack slots for a 32 bit VM. The VM is free to reorder the parameters in memory as it likes (and 64 bit VM *must* do this anyway because references where defined as *one* slot large in the JLS).

Comment: @Durandal: there’s [CompressedOps](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) which is now enabled by default. So references may still take one slot on 64Bit JVMs.

Comment: @Holger Thats true, with compressed OOPs reference *may* still be only 32 bits in size. Thanks for the clarification. My statement only applies to a fully 64 bit exploiting VM (that is one exceeding the compressed OOPs heap size limit, e.g. >32GB for Hotspot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still the case.  The jvm spec was not changed for 64bit jvms:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7

Comment: Wow! I thought that issue went away a long time ago.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - it does in practice, but not in the spec.

Comment: @jtahlborn there is no need then to use volatile as these types are stored in a 64bit block, even though spec says different?

Comment: @blue-sky I'm curious which use case sepcifically would be enabled if atomicity for non-volatile, long/double fields would be guaranteed. They would still subject to all the intricacies of the java memory model. I can't think of a case where atomicity alone would buy you anything because of the lack of a "happend-before" relationship with respect to other threads.

Comment: @blue-sky - doesn't matter what the OS arch is, it only matters how the jvm is implemented.  so, you are at the mercy of the jvm impl if you want to "depend" on that functionality.