# What is the importance of synchronized method in stopping one Thread from another?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

From the book "Effective java" i have following famous code of stopping one thread from another

```
 public class StopThread {
     private static boolean stopRequested;
     private static synchronized void requestStop() {
          stopRequested = true;
     }
     private static synchronized boolean stopRequested() {
          return stopRequested;
     }
     public static void main(String[] args)
                            throws InterruptedException {
          Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   int i = 0;
                   while (!stopRequested()) {
                       i++;
                   }
               }
          });
          backgroundThread.start();
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
          requestStop();
     }
}
```

A line is written there that is "**synchronization has no effect unless both read and write
operations are synchronized.**"But it is clear that if we don't use `synchronized` keyword with method `requestStop` the code will work fine,i.e,it terminates nearly after 1 second which is desired.One thing more here is that if we don't synchronize both the method we will(most probably) go into infinite loop because of code optimization.So my questions are:-
1.How and in what scenario things can go wrong if we don't synchronize 'stopRequested' method?Although here if we don't synchronize it,the program runs as desired,i.e,it terminates nearly in 1sec.
2.Does `synchronized` keyword enforces the VM to stop optimization each time?

Comment: "But it is clear that if we don't use synchronized keyword with method requestStop the code will work fine" on your JVM with your architecture (x86 is outlier of memory models). Have you tried this on a big iron Azul machine and their own JVM? On Aarch64 or alpha that both have rather weak memory models? No? Well then how do you know it works? You can't prove that something works by testing with concurrent code, you can only prove that it's broken that way.

Comment: @Voo - *You can't prove that something works by testing with concurrent code, you can only prove that it's broken that way* - perfect. :)

Comment: @Voo Then how would i make decisions about such kind of things in my mind by testing it on my pc only?

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918252/what-jvm-synchronization-practices-can-i-ignore-assuming-i-know-i-will-run-on-x6/25076347#25076347

Comment: @Rouftantical You can't, that's the point. The only way to know if a concurrent system is correct is by knowing the java memory model and convincing yourself that the given code is correct. This is hard however you do it and very easy to make errors (even if you make a formal proof, it's easy to make a mistake there). Nobody ever said concurrency was easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.How and in what scenario things can go wrong if we don't synchronize 'stopRequested' method?Although here if we don't synchronize it,the program runs as desired,i.e,it terminates nearly in 1sec**.

Things can go wrong if JVM decides to optimize the code within the run method of your backgroundThread. The read of stopRequested() can be reordered for optimization by JVM because of which it may never call the stopRequested() method again. But these days almost all JVM implementations take care of this and hence without making stopRequested as synchronized your code will still run fine. Also point to be noted here is that if you donot make stopRequested synchronized then the change done to stopRequested boolean variable may not be seen immediately by other non synchronized threads. Only if you used synchronization can the other threads immediately detect any change as an entry into synchronized method clears the cache and loads the data from the memory fresh. This immediate detection of memory changes is important in a highly concurrent system

**2) Does synchronized keyword enforces the VM to stop optimization each time?**

Synchronized keyword doesnot enforce VM to stop optimization but it makes it to adhere to the things listed below. VM can still do an optimization but it has to take care of the below things. 
Synchronization effectively does the following things:-

1. It guarantees happens before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
2. It guarantees memory visibility that is all the modifications done within the block which may be cached are immediately flushed before the exit of synchronization block which results in any other synchronized thread to see the memory updates immediately. This will be important in case of highly concurrent systems.

Comment: In second point as you said " which results in any other synchronized thread to see the memory updates immediately ".Is it necessary that the " other" thread which sees the update should be synchronized? Please reply.

Comment: @Rouftantical No the other thread need not be synchronized in which case it may not see the change done by synchronized thread immediately. This becomes more pronounced in a highly concurrent system with too many threads in which case some of the non synchronized threads may miss out the updates done by the synchronized thread just immediately after but after a few milli/micro seconds they would pick up the change.

Comment: Sorry I didnot get you.

Comment: If you want to avoid synchronizing the methods which does only read operation of variables and you want all the threads to have updated data immediately then as mentioned by others you can make the read variable as volatile.

Answer (score 1):

**1.How and in what scenario things can go wrong if we don't synchronize 'stopRequested' method?**

Assume if one thread is writing (updating) the field `stopRequested`, now before the first thread updates the value of `stopRequested` from requestStop(), another thread can read the value of `stopRequested` by calling `stopRequested()` (if `stopRequested()` was not *synchronized*.  Thus it would not get the updated value.

**2.Does synchronized keyword enforces the VM to stop optimization each time?**
Not always, *Escape Analysis* implemented from JDK6U23 also plays a part in this. 
Synchronization creates a memory barrier which ensures a *happens-before* relationship. i.e, any block of code executed after a synchronized block is sure to have the updated value (changes made earlier are reflected).

Statements can be executed *out-of-order* within a synchronized block to improve efficiency provided the *happens-before* holds good. On the other hand a *synchronized block* can be removed by the JVM if it determines that the block can be accessed only by a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

Changes by a thread to a variable are not necessarily seen right away by other threads. Using synchronized here makes sure that the update by one thread is visible to the other thread.

1) The change would possibly not become visible to the other thread. In the absence of synchronization or volatile or atomic fields there's no assurance when the other thread will see the change.

2) The synchronized keyword helps the VM decide on limits on instruction reordering and on what the VM can optimize.

Testing this on your machine will not necessarily display the same results as using a server with more processors. Different platforms may do more optimizing. So just because it works on your machine doesn't necessarily mean it's ok.

Comment: So it is not "safe" to consider ourself luck by not synchronizing `request stop` as the things may go wrong another day?

Comment: @Rouftantical: right. different vm implementations on different hardware have leeway to do their own things. Using things like synchronized tells the vm where the limits are on what it can get by with, so that you can run the code on a different platform and have some assurance it won't be broken there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make stopRequested volatile. Then method stopRequest does not have to be synchronized, because it does not change anything.

Comment: Thats exactly the next topic in the book