# Are 64 bit operations atomic for a 32 bit app on 64 bit Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit, atomic

So this document says that running 64 bit Windows gives you 64 bit atomicity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This post indicates that you have to run a 64 bit app to gain 64 bit atomicity: [atomicity in 32/64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123326/atomicity-in-32-64-bit)

I'm developing a Win32 console app. So, if I understand correctly, I have to use 32 bit types to get atomicity, right? I cannot assume a 64 bit type has atomic writes/reads?

Comment: 32-bit apps run in 32-bit instruction set, which needs to issue two instructions in order to transfer 64 bits from memory to two 32-bit registers. The execution may very well switch to a different thread in between these two instructions. The fact that the application is running on 64-bit Windows doesn't change that.

Comment: Quoted from the page you linked to: "Reads and writes to 64-bit values are not guaranteed to be atomic on 32-bit Windows."

Comment: @RaymondChen: this doesn't directly address the question, which is about a 32-bit application running on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: How many 32-bit instructions do you know that take 64-bit operands (basically just the SIMD extensions)? It's not possible to ensure memory access occurs indivisibly when it has to broken into multiple operations. Unfortunately, the fact that your application is running on a 64-bit kernel does not change the equation any - it is actually running in a compatibility layer and has none of the benefits of x64.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point. The text should read "in 32-bit applications." You can sort of get there from here by realizing that 32-bit applications running on 64-bit Windows are running in an emulator that is simulating 32-bit Windows, so the rules for 32-bit Windows still apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a 64-bit app, 64-bit read/write operations can be automatic because the compiler can take advantage of the x64 extended instruction set which has atomic 64-bit read/write operations.

In 32-bit code on a 64-bit OS & hardware, on the other hand, if the app needs to read/write 64-bit data, there are no 64-bit read/write instructions available so the compiler has to generate (at least) two read/write operations. Because the OS could pre-empt the process in between the two reads/writes, you should employ the `Interlockedxxx` API's.

Note: You *can* build [64-bit Win32 console apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx) if you want. In this case, the compiler can generate code that uses the 64-bit read/write op's.

Of course, since your code might want to read/write data types that are larger than 64-bit (e.g. SSE2/3, AVX, etc), thus requiring multiple read/write op's, you should [employ the appropriate intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds.aspx) to ensure that the required operations are made atomic.

Rather than assume that you can rely on the compiler to do the right thing for your specific scenario, I'd recommend employing the necessary API's and intrinsics to explicitly declare which of your operations **MUST** be atomic. This way you won't care if your code is compiled for x64, x64, ARM, MIPS, etc.

Comment: Well of course i should do that. But I may just use floats instead of doubles :)

Comment: Take care with assumptions about ANY data types. Several factors could end up with code requiring atomicity NOT being generated in an assumed atomic fashion by the compiler. If you need something to be atomic, declare it to be so! :)

Comment: Alright, so in my particular application I'm sharing a chunk of memory between 2 threads (probably on different cores). 1 reads the other writes. If I am going to be a good programmer (likelihood of this is questionable), I would simply use InterlockedExchange to assign the floats and leave the reads as-is, right? Although that completely removes the satisfaction of getting away with something, which is only worth it if it is replaced by the satisfaction of something working correctly.

Comment: Without `InterlockedExchange` or similar, the compiler could very well optimize away the reads, or delay the writes, or reorder reads and writes in ways you don't expect . It's in its right to assume that memory doesn't magically change by forces outside the currently executing codepath. In the context of that article, "atomic" only means "you won't experience tearing" - there are no coherence or ordering guarantees. It only talks about what the CPU can do at assembly level, but not what the compiler can do when it translates your C++ code down to assembly.

Comment: You can use `InterlockedCompareExchange` et al for proper atomic reads. Just pass the same value for the last two parameters - then it's a no-op except for the side effect of returning the current value of the variable. Or, with sufficiently modern compiler, use `std::atomic`